# Unable to configure views, urls.py SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django

I'm having issue while configuring views and I am following django 1.5 official tutorial.
Here is my Code for polls/urls.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns ('', 
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'), 
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='reults'),
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),

)
```

Below is my polls/views.py

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")

def detail(request, poll_id):
return HttpResponse("You’re looking at poll %s." % poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
return HttpResponse("You’re looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
return HttpResponse("You’re voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

In polls/urls.py I've also tried 
    url(r'^(?P\d+)/detail/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
instead of 
    url(r'^(?P\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
Error I'm getting is

File "C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite\polls\urls.py", line 7
    url(r'^(?P\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[31/Dec/2013 06:06:34] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 84890

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

should be

```
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

You missed the parentness and you missed a comma after `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')`.

Comment: It is giving me same error...i've corrected it though. Seems like the problem is in views.vote URL configuration.

Comment: I am really sorry for inconvenience actually i've typed in the code again and again so that's why making small mistakes.

Comment: However its giving me again the error.    File "C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite\polls\views.py", line 7
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite\polls
\views.py on line 7, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pe
p-0263.html for details
[31/Dec/2013 07:08:37] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 97589

Comment: Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the first line of views.

Comment: Tried it and its giving me error on that particular line where its added. Also tried a lot of solution up till now from last 3 hours.

Comment: Thanks for help but I will have to start it from scrap. Meanwhile if you can suggest something else I will be really thankful. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure missing the comma caused your error pasted, you can accept it as the right answer.